# ERROR MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered. The expected hash value:

Tags: experience-editor, media-library

For all uses of MediaManager I have code like:

```
  string mediaItem = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(sourceItem, mediaUrlOptions);
   itemUrl = HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(mediaItem);
```

I do have setting set:

```
 <setting name="Media.RequestProtection.SharedSecret">
```

And yet when in preview mode I see the error:
ERROR MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered. The expected hash value:

Any pointers? Thank you

Comment: have a look here, you may get som,e help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310016/how-to-handle-image-tag-in-rich-text-field-in-sitecore-so-that-it-can-handle-th

Comment: @GauravAgarwal  Errors are not generated by RTE, but previewing the actual site where data is from API (regular table with couple of country flags).

Comment: You will need the `SharedSecret` set as described in this answer: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/249/mediarequestprotection-an-invalid-missing-hash-value-was-encountered#answer-252